# MySQLI statement with WHERE AND

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to update a table based on looking up a row where the 'mentor_id' and 'feedbacker_id' match the variables input. I'm using the statement:

```
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "UPDATE feedback SET (last_updated=?, p2q1=?, p2q2=?, p2q3=?, p2q4=?) 
    WHERE mentor_id=? AND feedbacker_id=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssss", $time,$p2q1,$p2q2,$p2q3,$p2q4,$mentor_id,$feedbacker_id);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

I've tested each of the variables before the MySQLI statement to check they all contain info and the do. I don't receive any feedback on the PHP page (no errors) and the row isn't updated in the table. Can anybody help with that might be wrong?

> Thanks for the advice. I'm getting the error:

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(last_updated=?,     p1q1=?, p1q2=?, p1q3=?, p1q4=?) WHERE mentor_id=? AND feedba' at line 1"
```

I don't see any obvious errors in the syntax though?

> Fixed based on the suggestion by @gerald-schneider:

```
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "UPDATE feedback SET last_updated=?, p2q1=?, p2q2=?, p2q3=?, p2q4=? WHERE mentor_id=? AND feedbacker_id=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    /* Bind parameters. Types: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssss", $time, $p2q1, $p2q2, $p2q3, $p2q4, $mentor_id, $feedbacker_id);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

}
```

Comment: What does PDO have to do with your question? Do you want to migrate that code to PDO?

Comment: have you actually created a new PDO object?

Comment: If the execute fails, you won't see the error unless you `echo mysqli_error($mysqli);`  Check the return codes with `if (!mysqli_stmt_bind_param())` and `if (!mysqli_stmt_execute())` just as you did with the prepare, and you need an `else` case on the prepare call to `else echo mysqli_error($mysqli);`

Comment: Sorry about adding PDO.. my bad. Title updated.

Comment: Have you tried removing the opening and closing parenthesis? `(` and `)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parentheses from your query. The [UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) is

```
UPDATE table SET x=foo WHERE y=bar
```

without parentheses.

Comment: thank you @gerald-schneider. that worked. I updated the statement to '"UPDATE feedback SET last_updated=?, p2q1=?, p2q2=?, p2q3=?, p2q4=? WHERE mentor_id=? AND feedbacker_id=?"'